# Pointer translation for linked lists

Tags: c, pointers

I have been trying to get this pointer code translated for sometime. Please let me know how it translates to?

```
container->first = element;
```

is actually:

```
(*container).first = element;
```

How can I translate the following?

```
container->last->next = element;
&a->header;
```

Comment: Have you tried: `(*(*container).last).next = element`?

Comment: Do the same thing you did for the first example, you just need to do it more than once: `a->b->c == (*a).b->c == (*(*a).b).c`.

Comment: How does it translate in this case? &a->header. Is it *a.header or *(&a).header?

Comment: Is there anyway to translate this? &a->header;

Comment: Look it up in your precedence chart. ( `->` is above unary `&` on my chart)

Comment: What does &a->header; mean? Pass the address of a to header? Is there anyway to translate &a->header in terms of .?

Comment: okay &a->header is actually &(a->header). :)

Comment: @RajS: &((*a).header)